# Rewrite module NGINX

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Hi how can I rewrite my URL into a certain format?

Example:

```
# I have this URL
http://www.mywebsite.com
```

I would like it to be written into something like this

```
https://www.mywebsite.com.truesite.com
```

So if my URL is something like this

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/newsite?test=message

# it will be rewritten into like this
https://www.mywebsite.com.truesite.com/newsite?test=message
```

I'm not really good when it comes to regex so I have no idea on how to accomplish this on NGINX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is an HTTP to HTTPS passing, you need more than the rewrite module of Nginx.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;
    return 301 https://www.mywebsite.com.truesite.com$request_uri;
}
```

You need to have another block on your https website which includes SSL.